# Can I use img:hover to get another element?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

So is it possible to make this work

```
#element img:hover #otherelement {...}
```

like

```
#element:hover #otherelement {...}
```

it's important for img to stay specified, because images are automatic in what I'm making.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is selecting next element(s) by:

#### Adjacent sibling combinator

[`element1 + element2`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) Selects every `element2` element that are placed immediately after `element1` element(s). They're *siblings*.

```
#element img:hover + #otherelement
```

If the `#otherelement` is placed right after `img`, it'll be selected when `img` is hovered.

Another option is:

#### General sibling combinator

[`element1 ~ element2`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) Matches occurrences of `element2` that are preceded by `element1` while they have the same parent. They're *siblings* too, but `element2` doesn't have to be immediately preceded by `element1`.

```
#element img:hover ~ #otherelement
```

If `#otherelement` and `img` are siblings, and `#otherelement` is placed somewhere after the `img`, it'll be selected when `img` is hovered.

**[Here is an example](http://jsbin.com/idosos/3/edit)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" alt="Sport">
    <div class="text">This is a text.</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#parent {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: .3s all;
  -moz-transition: .3s all;
  transition: .3s all;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

#parent img:hover + .text {
  top: -40px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As `img` cannot hold any other nested tag, I assume you are targeting the adjacent element, you can use adjacent selector here using `+`

```
#element img:hover + #otherelement {...}
```

The above selector will select the element next to `img` tag when the image is hovered.

Note: Above selector will work only if you've your markup like

```
<div id="element">
   <img src="#" />
   <div  id="otherelement"></div >
</div >
```

But will fail if you've markup like

```
<div id="element">
   <img src="#" />
</div >
<div  id="otherelement"></div >
```

Answer (score 1):

What your first selector is looking for is something called `#otherelement` *inside* an image. Images can't have child elements.

If the element is a *sibling* of the image, you might want to try `img:hover~#otherelement` or `img:hover+#otherelement`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, try:

```
#element:hover + #otherelement {...}
```

or

```
#element:hover ~ #otherelement {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the :hover pseudo class on any element. There are considerations to be made in regards to cross-browser. You can use a polyfill like Selectivizr for that, though.

As for your question, you might want to consider targeting a shared ancestor for both elements you are trying to target with the hover and apply your styles that way.