# Alternate row colors between two divs

Tags: css

I'm not sure if this is possible in CSS, but if it is, I would appreciate some help.

I have HTML similar to the following:

```
<div class="group"></div>

<div class="group"></div>
<div class="group subgroup"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>

<div class="group"></div>
<div class="group subgroup"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
```

Is it possible to alternate the background colors of the row classes? Always starting with the same color? I've been having trouble achieving this using nth-child and I'm assuming it's because of the group/subgroup classes.

Manual html markup in jsfiddle of an example data set that could be returned and how it is designed to be styled:
http://jsfiddle.net/Qr5Za/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 'always starting with the same color' means that the first row after
>   group/subgroup starts with red

If so, you can set `background-color` of the first `.row` red and the others `magenta` by:

```
.group ~ .row { /* select all rows comes after each group */
    background-color: magenta;
}

.group + .row { /* select and override the first row after each group */
    background-color: red;
}
```

**[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/ozevek/1/edit)**

These selectors are called **General sibling combinator** `~` and **Adjacent sibling combinator** `+`, you can find [more details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18242244/1725764).

#### Update

All new CSS3 selectors like [`:nth-child(n)`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo), [`:nth-of-type(n)`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-of-type-pseudo) matches every element that is the `n`th child or type, **of its parent**.

So the only way to achieve [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Qr5Za/), is putting `.row`s in a wrapper for each block:

```html
<div class="group">This is a group</div>
<div class="group subgroup">This is a subgroup</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="row">This is the first row</div>
  <div class="row">This is the second row</div>
  <div class="row">This is the third row</div>
  <div class="row">This is the forth row</div>
</div>
```

And selecting `odd` and `even` rows based on their position in the `.wrap`er *(their parent)*:

```
.row:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
}

.row:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: magenta;
}
```

**[JSBin Demo #2](http://jsbin.com/ozevek/3/edit)**

Comment: The row html markup will be created dynamically, in this example, if I add a third row after the first subgroup it stops alternating colors.

Comment: Did you check the demo? I tried, It doesn't stop alternating.check the current demo please.

Comment: So this is what I'm seeing, I switched over to jsfiddle to make sure I didn't have any caching issues with JSBin. http://jsfiddle.net/WLJHu/ this is the first row is red, this is the second row is magenta, this is the third row is magenta, and the second subgroup this is the first row is red.

If the third, fifth, etc (however many were created) were red that'd be exactly what I'm looking for. I'm on chrome by the way if that matters.

Comment: What it supposed to be?

Comment: I just edited my comment above, the rows after the subgroups are supposed to be alternating colors. In this example starting with red, going to magenta, going to red, going to magenta, going to red. And then after the second subgroup, it should start with red again, go to magenta, go to red, etc.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Doing manual markup, I could expect to see data and would want to display it like this for example http://jsfiddle.net/Qr5Za/

Comment: This help so much, I was confused, let me a moment.

Comment: You've scratched your head as much as I have and came up with the same conclusion I think...

Comment: This like this is the way to go after playing around with it for awhile. Thanks Hashem Qolami and @brbcoding for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
.row:nth-of-type(n) + .row:nth-of-type(even){
  background: green;
}

.row:nth-of-type(n) + .row:nth-of-type(odd){
  background: orange;
}
.group.subgroup + .row:nth-of-type(n) {
  background: blue;
}
```

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/5Rg62/)**

Comment: So the 'always starting with the same color' means that the first row after group/subgroup starts with red. I had something somewhat working but it was always alternating depending on the contents.

Comment: Similarly to another answer on here, if I add another row markup in the first subgroup. You will see that the first row starts with green, and the second row after the second subgroup starts with red.

Comment: Edit! So I changed the code the first row that is adjacent to be green, and added a fifth row and it still alternates between subgroups. http://jsfiddle.net/SRAKn/

Comment: It's still not quite right... change the background of that last one to green and you'll see what I mean

Comment: Yup, just noticed that. Oops.

Comment: I hate to say it, but I'm baffled... I don't think it can be done without actually wrapping each group inside it's own container. -- I'd love to be proven wrong though.