# CSS: Hiding another div

Tags: javascript, html, css, siblings

I have a parent div in my code, and 2 child divs. I want that on hovering the first child, the second child to hide. I want to do that only with css or js.

[**Here's my Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Arkenn/jxq2M/)

```html
<div class="parrent">
    <div id="child1">
        Hide child2
    </div>

    <div id="child2">  
        I must hide
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Update the question with the CSS aswell please. We shouldn't have to be pulling it from the fiddle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use img:hover to get another element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18242217/can-i-use-imghover-to-get-another-element)

Comment: just add a + to your css like this #child1:hover + #child2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```css
#child1:hover ~ #child2 {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hVLHD/)

This uses the [**General sibling combinator**](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/) `~`

> **~** selector: The general sibling combinator selector is very similar to the adjacent sibling combinator selector we just looked at. The difference is that that the element being selected doesn't need immediately succeed the first element, but can appear anywhere after it.

---

You can also use the **[Adjacent sibling combinator](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)** `+`, depending on the rest of your code.

> **+** selector: An adjacent sibling combinator selector allows you to select an element that is directly after another specific element.

```css
#child1:hover + #child2 {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hVLHD/1/)

Comment: Or: `#child1:hover + #child2`

Comment: @AllanChua, Yes it will: http://jsfiddle.net/hVLHD/2/ - the one not working would be `+`

Comment: @AllanChua Not true, `General sibling combinator` means it doesn't matter if there were some siblings between two selectors.

Comment: @AllanChua I emphasized on what Sergio mentioned, please read my comment again with care.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Now I can finnaly finish my school project.

Comment: @Arkenn, glad I could help! If you want you can also click to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#child1:hover #child2 {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

This will not work as now you're saying that `#child2` must be a child of `#child1`.

What you can do is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#child1').hover(function(){
        $('#child2').hide();
    }, function(){
        $('#child2').show();
    });
});
```

Or use the CSS code:

```
#child1:hover ~ #child2 {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#child1').on('mouseover',function(){
        $("#child2").hide();
    }).on('mouseout',function(){
        $("#child2").show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Before doing this you should know how to refer to a **sibling** element of an element in CSS.

instead of the following syntax-

```
#child1:hover #child2
```

You need the following:

```
#child1:hover+#child2
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jxq2M/3/)**

N.B. Basically `+` is for a reference to a sibling

**[Reference](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)**

Comment: I respect your answer which is very elaborative.